# How grouping and adding array by date in php?

Tags: php

I have an arrangement that combiar need to return or exchange me the following result.

How could do it?

`Array
([2-1] => Array
        (
            [20150331] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 20150331
                    [type_room] => Doble
                    [rate] => 110
                    [comission_percentage] => 15
                    [net_rate_to_pay] => 93.5
                    [service] => AI
                    [adults] => 2
                    [children] => 1
                )`

```
        [20150401] => Array
            (
                [date] => 20150401
                [type_room] => Doble
                [rate] => 110
                [comission_percentage] => 15
                [net_rate_to_pay] => 93.5
                [service] => AI
                [adults] => 2
                [children] => 1
            )

    )

[1-0] => Array
    (
        [20150331] => Array
            (
                [date] => 20150331
                [type_room] => Single
                [rate] => 95
                [comission_percentage] => 15
                [net_rate_to_pay] => 80.75
                [service] => AI
                [adults] => 1
                [children] => 0
            )

        [20150401] => Array
            (
                [date] => 20150401
                [type_room] => Single
                [rate] => 95
                [comission_percentage] => 15
                [net_rate_to_pay] => 80.75
                [service] => AI
                [adults] => 1
                [children] => 0
            )

    )
```

)

How do I combine to leave me this array?

`Array
(
    [2-1] => Array
        (
            [20150331] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 20150331
                    [type_room] => Doble
                    [rate] => 110
                    [comission_percentage] => 15
                    [net_rate_to_pay] => 93.5
                    [service] => AI
                    [adults] => 2
                    [children] => 1
                )`

```
       [20150331] => Array
            (
                [date] => 20150331
                [type_room] => Single
                [rate] => 95
                [comission_percentage] => 15
                [net_rate_to_pay] => 80.75
                [service] => AI
                [adults] => 1
                [children] => 0
            )        
    )

[1-0] => Array
    (   [20150401] => Array
            ([date] => 20150401
                [type_room] => Single
                [rate] => 95
                [comission_percentage] => 15
                [net_rate_to_pay] => 80.75
                [service] => AI
                [adults] => 1
                [children] => 0
            )

        [20150401] => Array
            (
                [date] => 20150401
                [type_room] => Doble
                [rate] => 110
                [comission_percentage] => 15
                [net_rate_to_pay] => 93.5
                [service] => AI
                [adults] => 2
                [children] => 1
            )
    )
```

)

How do I group to add their fields for jumping me this final array?

`Array
(
    [2-1] => Array
        (
            [20150331] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 20150331
                    [type_room] => Doble
                    [rate] => 205
                    [comission_percentage] => 30
                    [net_rate_to_pay] => 173.80
                    [service] => AI

                    [adults] => 2
                    [children] => 1
                    [count] => 1
                )

        )
    [1-0] => Array
        (

            [20150401] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 20150401
                    [type_room] => Single
                    [rate] => 205
                    [comission_percentage] => 30
                    [net_rate_to_pay] => 179.80
                    [service] => AI
                    [adults] => 1
                    [children] => 0
                )

        )
)`

thanks

Comment: You have 2 criterias, first combine dates, but what happens if you have 3+ different addult-children combinations??? not clear logic...

Comment: What you want is to bring together and accumulate totals rooms containing the same date.